# Mapbox Tiling Service with Cesium

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, cesiumjs, vector-tiles

I have the Mapbox vector tiles on "Mapbox Tiling Service" (MTS). But I am not sure, how can I use MTS in my Cesium.js app. Does anyone have any insights into loading Tiles from MTS in Cesium?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a custom ImageryProvider(maybe MapboxVectorTileImageryProvider) that implements this interface.

https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/ImageryProvider.html?classFilter=ImageryProvider

In MapboxVectorTileImageryProvider you can use [Mapbox-vector-tiles-basic-js-renderer](https://github.com/landtechnologies/Mapbox-vector-tiles-basic-js-renderer)